# Implementing search suggestions in flutter

Tags: flutter, search, tags

My desire is to implement a search by tags function  that returns suggestions as the user continues to input the search term.

My model  has the following structure

```
class BuyerPost{
  final String postId;
  final String buyer;
  final String description;
  final GeoPoint locationCoordinates;
  final List tags;// search by this
  final List imageUrls;
  final String category;
  final Timestamp postTime;
  final Timestamp expireTime;
  final int responsesCount;
  final String status;

  BuyerPost({
    this.postId,
    this.buyer,
    this.description,
    this.locationCoordinates,
    this.tags,
    this.imageUrls,
    this.category,
    this.postTime,
    this.expireTime,
    this.responsesCount,
    this.status,
  });

}
```

As in the snippet above, the tags property of the model is a list of tags set by the user.

So far i have only implemented the search to return documents only if the search term exactly matches the tag name in the tags list.

**Example:**
if a user searches 'bl' in a case where the post has tags like `tags:['black','white']` it will not return anything till he/she completes it to like 'black'.

Here is the snippet for searching

```
  //single buyer post
  Stream <List<BuyerPost>> get searchBuyerPost {
    try {
      return buyerPostCollection.snapshots()
          .map(yieldSearchedBuyerPosts);
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

   List<BuyerPost> yieldSearchedBuyerPosts(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    try {
      return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
        print(doc.data['name']);
        return BuyerPost(
          postId: doc.data['postId'] ?? '',
          description: doc.data['description'] ?? '',
          locationCoordinates: doc.data['locationCoordinates'] ?? '',
          imageUrls: doc.data['imageUrl'] ?? [],
          tags: doc.data['tags'] ?? [],
          category: doc.data['category'] ?? '',
          postTime: doc.data['postTime']?? Timestamp(0,0),
          expireTime: doc.data['expireTime']?? Timestamp(0,0),
          responsesCount: doc.data['responsesCount']?? 0,
          status: doc.data['status'] ?? '',
        );
      }).where((post) =>
          post.tags.contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase()
      )
      ).toList();
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I would like the search to work with suggestions too. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by keywords? You want it to match "bl" as "black" ?

Comment: Yeah, more like suggstions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have more control over string match I suggest you take a look into **Regex**.

Here is an example:

```
List<BuyerPost> match(String searchString, List<BuyerPost> posts) {
  RegExp searchedStringRegex = RegExp(searchString);
  return posts.where((post) => post.tags.any((tag) => searchedStringRegex.hasMatch(tag)));
}
```

Here the `match` function will return any tag which contains the searched string.

Comment: Im not sure of how to implement this in my case because what i want to return is not a list of the tags rather the list of post objects with tags matching search term

Comment: Just pass the posts as argument and check in their tags. I'll write it for you in a couple of hours if you didn't manage to do it.

Comment: Id appreciate that